# Dereferencing vector pointers with a range based for loop

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

This is the code from my main() function:

```
std::map<int, std::string> candyMap;
std::vector<House*> houseVector;
std::ifstream abodeFile{houseFile};
std::string houseLine;
if(abodeFile.is_open())
{
    while(getline(abodeFile, houseLine))
    {
        houseVector.push_back(new House(houseLine, candyMap));
    }
}

std::cout << std::setw(11) << " ";
for(auto i:houseVector)
{
    std::cout << std::setw(11) << i;
}
```

I am trying to print out the elements from houseVector. Obviously, with the above code I get the addresses of the elements. When I do `*i`, I get an operator error with `<<`. What is the correct way to dereference here?

Comment: You need to overload `operator<<` for `House`. Or print all its members one by one by using `i->member`.

Comment: What do you want to see by cout ing an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to overload `ostream <<` operator, e.g.:

```
class House
{
    int member;
public:
    explicit House (int i) : member(i) {}
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const House& house);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const House& house)
{
    os <<house.member << '\n';
    return os;
}
```

Live on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/wpqaQJ)

---

Or without friend:

```
class House
{
    int member;
public:
    explicit House (int i) : member(i) {}

    std::ostream &write(std::ostream &os) const { 
        os<<member<<'\n';
        return os;
    }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const House& house) { 
     return house.write(os);
}
```

Live on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zQVhJ3)

Comment: The member I want to access is private

Comment: @turing042 you should make this overload as member of House.

Comment: @OblivionreinstateOurMonica: You can't make it a member of House because House is not the first argument. But you can make it a friend (and of course, you can implement that friend inside the class definition). Note that even if you define it as friend inside the class definition, it doesn't become a member (e.g. you cannot access it using `House::operator<<`).